# discord.js Can you log the messages that the Bot get per DM?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hello i want to log the messages that the Bot becomes per DM in a Channel that i choose. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can log the messages that bot get in the dms

I'll write sample code for you:

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm'){ 
     // put your code here
     console.log(message.content)

}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, direct messages to a bot have `guild` property set to `null`.

```
client.on("message", msg => { 
   if (msg.guild == null) {
       // your action here, for example
       console.log(msg.content);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `msg.channel.type` to determine the message's channel type.

```js
client.on('message', msg => { 
   if (msg.channel.type === 'dm') {
       channel.send(msg);
   }
});
```

`channel` is an object of type [TextChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel) where you would like your message to be logged to.